# Test multiple react-select components on same page using Cypress

Tags: reactjs, cypress, react-select

I am trying to test react-select components (v5) on a page using cypress. I can do this using the css classname when there is only one react select component on a page, but when there are multiple ones I'm having trouble adding a unique identifier to the component. I've tried adding a `dataCy` attribute to the select component but it doesn't show up in the DOM.

```
cy.get("[dataCy=reports-menu]").click()

<Select
            options={reportItems}
            isSearchable
            className="mb-4"
            placeholder="Water System Reports"
            onChange={handleMenuChange}
            defaultValue={{ label: "Inventory", value: "inventory" }}
            dataCy="reports-menu"
          />
```

I've also tried calling the component out by placeholder like this:
 `cy.get(".css-319lph-ValueContainer").should("contain", "Inventory").click();`

and then clicking on that item but I still get an error that

```
cy.click() can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 2 elements. Pass { multiple: true } if you want to serially click each element
```

How can I specificity which react-select component on a page I want to click on when a page may contain multiple react-select components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `aria-label="reports-menu"` to the react-select. This attribute adds to the inner `<input>` element, which may or may not be the element you want to click.

The Cypress selector is

```js
cy.get("[aria-label=reports-menu]")
```

You can also add `id="reports-menu"`, which gets added to the top-most div of the Select elements, most likely this is your click target.

The Cypress selector is

```js
cy.get("#reports-menu")
```

Comment: Thank you - using `id` worked. I thought I had tried that earlier...but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

With `contains` you can use a combination of selector and text.

```js
cy.contains('[placeholder="Water System Reports"]','Inventory').click()
```

Comment: I'm unable to do what you suggested because this react-select has a default value of `{ label: "Inventory", value: "inventory" }` which I am able to test by using the following `cy.get(".css-319lph-ValueContainer").should("contain", "Inventory")`. But as mentioned in the OP, doing that test fails because there are 2 react-select components with the same css class AND giving the select component a custom prop name not in the library isn't working.

Comment: `cy.contains` should only be yielding a single element, so as long as you have unique placeholder text this will do what you want.